# Format values in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Replace values from a column based on the following rule:  t**0345**_0400_d2 = **03:45**, or to keep only the first part of the value in time format. How can I do this?

Data structure:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Sample data:

```
df<-structure(list(serial = c(11011202, 11011202, 11011202, 11011202, 
11011202, 11011202, 11011202, 11011202, 11011202, 11011202, 11011202, 
11011202, 11011202, 11011202), `start/end` = c("Mon_start", "Mon_end", 
"Tue_start", "Tue_end", "Wed_start", "Wed_end", "Thur_start", 
"Thur_end", "Fri_start", "Fri_end", "Sat_start", "Sat_end", "Sun_start", 
"Sun_end"), value = c("t0345_0400_d2", "t1445_1500_d2", "t0415_0430_d3", 
"t0345_0400_d3", "t0700_0715_d4", "t1515_1530_d4", "t0415_0430_d5", 
"t1445_1500_d5", "t0415_0430_d6", "t0345_0400_d6", "t0415_0430_d7", 
"t0345_0400_d7", "t0415_0430_d1", "t0345_0400_d1")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(serial = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `start/end` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), value = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sub` to extract data in two capture groups and separate them by `:` -

```
transform(df, time = sub('t(\\d{2})(\\d{2}).*', '\\1:\\2', value))

#    serial  start.end         value  time
#1  11011202  Mon_start t0345_0400_d2 03:45
#2  11011202    Mon_end t1445_1500_d2 14:45
#3  11011202  Tue_start t0415_0430_d3 04:15
#4  11011202    Tue_end t0345_0400_d3 03:45
#5  11011202  Wed_start t0700_0715_d4 07:00
#6  11011202    Wed_end t1515_1530_d4 15:15
#7  11011202 Thur_start t0415_0430_d5 04:15
#8  11011202   Thur_end t1445_1500_d5 14:45
#9  11011202  Fri_start t0415_0430_d6 04:15
#10 11011202    Fri_end t0345_0400_d6 03:45
#11 11011202  Sat_start t0415_0430_d7 04:15
#12 11011202    Sat_end t0345_0400_d7 03:45
#13 11011202  Sun_start t0415_0430_d1 04:15
#14 11011202    Sun_end t0345_0400_d1 03:45
```